# How to convert the following code output in one line using join in python.. currently for two word input i am getting output in two lines

Tags: python, string

```
def cat_latin_word(text):
    """ convert the string in another form
    """

    constant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"

    for word in text.split():
        if word[0] in constant:
            word = (str(word)[-1:] + str(word)[:4] + "eeoow")
        else:
            word = (str(word) + "eeoow")
        print(word)



def main():
    """ converts"""
    text = input("Enter a sentence ")
    cat_latin_word(text)

main()
```

Comment: can you add some sample output you are expecting ?

Comment: I can see a good reason for using `join`, but why only on one line?

Comment: i am getting the output right ..that is for input ankit jaiswal..outtput is ankiteeoow
ljaiseeoow   but i want it in one line

Comment: @cdarke question corrected..i want output in one single line..currently i am getting splitted output.

Comment: @VikasDamodar i am expecting output in one single line..not splitted in two lines or more

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- Converting your code to "one line" doesn't make it better.
- No need to type out all consonants, use the `string` module and use `set` for O(1) lookup complexity.
- Use formatted string literals (Python 3.6+) for more readable and efficient code.
- No need to use `str` on variables which are already strings.
- For a single line, you can use a list comprehension with a ternary statement and `' '.join`.

Here's a working example:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

def cat_latin_word(text):

    consonants = (set(ascii_lowercase) | set(ascii_uppercase)) - set('aeiouAEIOU')

    print(' '.join([f'{word}eeow' if not word[0] in consonants else \
                    f'{word[-1:]}{word[:4]}eeoow' for word in text.split()]))

text = input("Enter a sentence ")
cat_latin_word(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a list to put all the words or use [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in a different way.
Example:

```
print(word, end="\t")
```

where here I use the keyword argument `end` to set it to `'\t'` ( by default is `'\n'`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply edited your code to return the results as a words separated by space.

```
def cat_latin_word(text):
    constant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
    result = []
    for word in text.split():
        if word[0] in constant:
            word = (str(word)[-1:] + str(word)[:4] + "eeoow")
            result.append(word)
        else:
            word = (str(word) + "eeoow")
            result.append(word)

    return ' '.join(result)

def main():
    text = 'ankit jaiswal'
    print(cat_latin_word(text))
```

Comment: the output is not comming correctly.Only one word is transforming